# Self Referencing ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started learning Rails. I have the following question.

I generated "User" models (table "users") and I want to add relation to manager. Manager is also a User. I want to be able to write:

```
user.manager # => returns User object
```

I tried to write it like this:

```
class User
  belongs_to :user, as: :manager
end
```

But it didn't work. Can you please help me.

Comment: what is your foreign key?

Comment: manager_id is users table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Manager` is referenced by `manager_id` field, then:

```
class User
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
end
```

You can also identify `subordinates` of the user using `has_many` relation:

```
class User
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
```

Try this

Comment: Thank you @ror-developer